# C# Razor Syntax - Output DayOfWeek Abbreviation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm outputting DayOfWeek in my view.  It will display as "Friday", I want to display it as "Fri".  How can I do that?

```
@item.StartDate.DayOfWeek
```

**Follow Up**

Thanks for the simple answer.  Here's a follow up though.  If I'm going to displaying DayOfWeek, Date and Month separately from that same StartDate field, is it better to do that in my view model, or better in the view with Razor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Straight from the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
@item.StartDate.ToString("ddd")
```

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up trying that after DayOfWeek the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

string month="ddd";
@item.StartDate(month);